# How to compress images stored in a .pdf

Tags: pdf, itext

I have the following code at a client site:

```
   private void writeBufferedImage2Pdf(PdfContentByte cb, BufferedImage img)
   {
      com.itextpdf.text.Image BWImage = com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(img, null, false);

      BWImage.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);  // from the lower left
      BWImage.scaleToFit(612,792);   // 8.5x11 (72 per inch)
      cb.addImage(BWImage, false);
   }
```

I have noticed that the size of the .pdf that gets generated larger than I would expect.   For instance, for a .pdf that has 8 .jpg images that totaled 3.3MB will explode to 28MB when the .pdf is generated with those 8 jpgs.

How can I apply a compression scheme to the image that is added to the .pdf?

I want to use a lossless compression algorithm for storing the image even if the original images are .jpg.

It happens that the images are text so we are also looking into converting to b/w, but that is a separate issue that will allow us to compress even further.

[EDIT] Although the image is originally .jpg image it is read into a buffered image because it is manipulated in the application.  Thinks like cropping, splitting, and resizing are done.  Watermark timestamps might also be added.

[EDIT] My hope is there is a lossless compression scheme I can apply when writing the image to the .pdf.  For instance, whatever scheme .png uses may not compress as much as .jpg, but it should still compress.  Or am I assuming it is not compressed and 28MB is a compressed size?

Comment: *"Although the image is originally .jpg image it is read into a buffered image because..."* - then **doing this** made the size *explode from 3.3MB to 28MB*, not adding them to the PDF. And as you *"want to use a lossless compression algorithm for storing the image"*, the size won't implode again (that is until you reduce colors etc).

Answer (score 1):

JPEG is an image format that is supported in the PDF specification. That means that iText doesn't need to process JPEG images. iText just puts the image bytes *as-is* inside the PDF if your code looks like this:

```
Image img = Image.getInstance(pathToJPG);
img.setAbsolutePosition(x, y);
cb.addImage(img);
```

However, you aren't taking advantage of the JPEG format. Instead of adding the JPEG bytes as-is, you are using a `java.awt.BufferedImage`. That makes the size of the image explode. The 3.3 MB can easily become 28 MB in the process.

Please adapt your code, and make sure that you add a real JPEG, not a `BufferedImage`. Your allegation that you are adding 3.3 MB of JPEG bytes isn't correct. You are adding AWT images, and that's a completely different game.